# Import xlsx with more than 16,384 columns

Tags: python, excel, import-from-excel

I have a dataset with over 16,384 columns. When I try to open it in excel, I get the error of "Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?". If I click ok, then I only get 16,384 columns.

When I try to import into python as an excel file, I get the error

File "C:\Users\ksilva\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 666, in do_row assert 0 <= colx < X12_MAX_COLS

AssertionError

When I try to import into python as a csv file, I only get 16,384 columns when there is more.

Is there another way to get all the columns, even if I need to split into multiple files?

Comment: An excel workbook is limited to at most 16384 columns. It isn't clear what this even means "to import an xlsx with more than 16384 columns" - it isn't possible to have such an xlsx.

Comment: What is the native file type? If it's a CSV, then I would think it would retain all columns. But if that CSV was first touched by Excel and saved, then it's limited. Ask the file creator to save as a CSV and then figure out where you can park it and load it into a database. You'll need to avoid Excel and use something else.

Comment: I would agree with the comments, but one potential workaround if you were desperate for Excel, would be to use multiple tabs. Admittedly this would be rather clunky (but so is so many columns...), but you could in theory get all your data in an Excel Workbook. You could loop for each 16384 columns...